# Ways to increase range of our present wireless router

Tags: wireless-networking, repeater, signal-strength

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to increase the range of my 802.11g router?](https://superuser.com/questions/29290/whats-the-best-way-to-increase-the-range-of-my-802-11g-router)

We are searching for a solution to increase the range of our present wireless solution.

We are currently using a Netgear DGND3700 router and while its good, its range is still limited and we'd like to amplify the strength of the signal as well as its range, as our building is quite old (built about 100 years ago) and has very thick walls.

Comment: Why was my question voted down and what can I do to improve it? We are having a genuine problem and we'd like help solving it. I was hoping a forum like this would provide some help/advise.

Comment: check the faq section before posting questions , shopping suggestions are not in the scope of this site

Comment: Your question was subjective and that probably got the downvotes and the votes to close.

Comment: Can someone please tell me how a repeater and range extender differ? Is a range extender, to put it crudely, just an antenna?